# Statistical test for data fit in power law relations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, power-law

I have two sets of data fit into power law relations y=a*x^b. What test do I do to test whether they are significantly different.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different options depending on what assumptions about the data that you are willing to make.

If you believe that the residuals around the fitted lines are normally distributed (or at least close enough) then you can fit using non-linear least squares methods.  Fit a full model that has parameters that allow the 2 curves to differ and a reduced model that fits a single curve to both groups, then test the difference in the models.  One concern with this looking at your data is that the green circles appear to vary more around the line than the black xs, so the equal variance assumption in most tests of this sort may not be reasonable.

A simpler approach would be to take the log of both sides of your equation, then it becomes a linear regression problem (this assumes that the errors are log-normally distributed and multiplied by the predictions rather than added) and you can fit a regular linear regression model between the log of x and the log of y, then look at the tests on the parameters that represent the differences.  (again the non-equality of variances could be a concern, but weighted least squares regression can help with this)

The second approach is easy enough that I would probably start there for exploration, your data will be the log of y, the log of x and an indicator variable for which group a point comes from (0 or 1), then fit a linear regression with the group variable, log(x), and the interaction between the 2 and look at the significance of the group variable for differences in $a$ (well technically log(a)) and the interaction for differences in $b$.  But look at the residuals and other diagnostics to decide if this is reasonable, or if a more complicated model or different probability distribution would be needed.